# How do I search for file while iterating through Folder IDs?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace

I'm trying to loop through standardized subfolder structures to check if each has a specific file type in it.  I  conducted small scale testing to ensure I could achieve proper searching of a folder and indicate presence or absence of a specific file type.  I was able to accurately conduct this check with a script.  I then wrote a for loop to iterate through  ~250 folders to conduct these checks, but then the file search no longer seems to work.  Other parts of the For loop work as expected, such as listing all the folder names, but then every cell is populated with an "x" indicated an error.

I've tried figure out why when the search is within a for loop it no longer behaves as expected, but cannot figure it out.

Script that works with a single file search:

```
function subfolderIterator(){


let FolderID = 'XXXX'

let testSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXXXXX')

try  {
let studioFourQuery = DriveApp.getFolderById(FolderID)
> .getFoldersByName('04 | Studio-4').next().searchFiles("fullText contains '.tfs'").next()

if (studioFourQuery){
testSpreadsheet.getRange("Audit!D2").setValue('√')

>  }
> }

catch (e){
testSpreadsheet.getRange("Audit!D2").setValue('X')
> }

try {
let studioFiveQuery = DriveApp.getFolderById(FolderId)
> .getFoldersByName('05 | Studio-5')
> .next().searchFiles("fullText contains '.tfs'").next()


if (studioFiveQuery){
testSpreadsheet.getRange("Audit!E2").setValue('√')
>   }
> }

catch (e){
testSpreadsheet.getRange("Audit!E2").setValue('X')
> }

> }
>
```

Script with for loop that  set all values to "x" in my spreadsheet.  Again, the script is properly listing all folder names:

```
> 
function FileSearchLoop(){

let clientFolder05ID = 'xxxx' 
let subNames = DriveApp.getFolderById(clientFolder05ID).getFolders()
let myarr = []

while (subNames.hasNext()){

let ids = subNames.next().getId()
>    //Logger.log(ids)

myarr.push(ids)
>    //Logger.log(myarr)

>  }

Logger.log(myarr)   

let testSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xyz')

for(i=0;i < myarr.length; i++){
let lr = testSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Audit').getLastRow()
let allClientFolderNames = DriveApp.getFolderById(myarr[i]).getName()
testSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Audit').getRange(lr+1,1).setValue(allClientFolderNames)


try  {
let studioFourQuery = DriveApp.getFolderById(myarr[i]).getFoldersByName('04 | Studio-4').next().searchFiles("fullText contains '.tfs'").next()

Logger.log(studioFourQuery)

if (studioFourQuery){
testSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Audit').getRange(lr+1,4).setValue('√')

>  }
> }

catch (e){
> //testSpreadsheet.getRange("Audit!D2").setValue('X')
testSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Audit').getRange(lr+1,4).setValue('X')
Logger.log(e)

> }

try {
let studioFiveQuery = DriveApp.getFolderById(myarr[i]).getFoldersByName('05 | Studio-5').next().searchFiles("fullText contains '.tfs'").next()


if (studioFiveQuery){
testSpreadsheet.getRange(lr+1,5).setValue('√')
>   }
> }

catch (e){
testSpreadsheet.getRange(lr+1,5).setValue('X')
>  }


> }


> }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you figure out this exception, you will probably get the answer.

```js
catch (e){
  Logger.log(e) // add this
  testSpreadsheet.getRange(lr+1,5).setValue('X')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I do have the error logging in the catch statement.  It returns "Exception: Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end."  I still don't understand why it isn't finding any files when looping, but can find them when only a single folder ID is used.